# Why does stack smashing happen while using newer version of glibc for older version of ubuntu?

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, debugging, glibc

I would like to use `glibc` version `2.31` for both `ubuntu 20.04` and `ubuntu 18.04` with the condition that it should not be installed in a system directory. However, I get an error.

I have Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04 as container_20_04

WORKDIR /root
RUN apt update && apt download libc6
RUN dpkg-deb -x libc6_2.31-0ubuntu9.2_amd64.deb /root/debs-install
RUN LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/root/debs-install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu mkdir some_dir

FROM ubuntu:18.04
WORKDIR /root
COPY --from=container_20_04 /root/debs-install /root/debs-install
RUN LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/root/debs-install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu mkdir some_dir
```

Note that the same command `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/root/debs-install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu mkdir some_dir` is run in both containers.

Then I run:

```
$ docker build . -t smashing
```

In the `ubuntu 20.04` container there is no error for a command, but in the ubuntu 18.04 container for the same command I get an error:

```
*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Could you please tell, what happens here or how it can be debugged?

Answer (score 1):

> Could you please tell, what happens here or how it can be debugged?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/50617) explains why setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to point to a different `libc.so.6` can *never* work: you *must* use matching `ld-linux` as well.